# Android, how to take phone number?

Tags: android, phone-number

I my application I have written following code in order to extract phone number. When I run it in emulator, everything is fine but when I run it on a real device, application crashes. what is your suggestion? I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` in manifest file.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView phoneNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNumber);
phoneNumber.setText(getMy10DigitPhoneNumber());
}
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
    }

    private String getMy10DigitPhoneNumber(){
        String s = getMyPhoneNumber();
        return s.substring(2);
    }

}
```

Comment: When I did this, the numbers were different between an emulator and a real device.  Consider removing the substring and seeing what you get.

Comment: "The application crashes" - but you don't think that an error message or stack trace would be helpful to post? :)

Comment: ya you are right, sorry i forgot it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLine1Number()` will return the phone number string if available and null if not available. So you should check for Null Pointer.

```
private String getMy10DigitPhoneNumber() {
        String s = getMyPhoneNumber();
        if(s == null) return "";
        else return s.substring(2);
}
```

Also check the length of the string returned by `getLine1Number()`. In my phone, i got a `""`string. In this case, `substring()` will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So check for length of `s` also before calling substring().

Comment: you are great man. the problem was because of length of string. I removed substring claus and it worked fine :) but I did not take phone number, just "". :(

Comment: @Hesam, Thanks. BTW, You can check Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> My Phone number in your mobile. This number is returned by getLine1Number(). If it is _Unknown_, then getLint1Number() will return null or "". 
Itseems it is Operator/SIM dependent.